# Select rows if a condition in a column is met

Tags: sql, databricks-sql

I'm faced with the following issue described below. I have a complex query with multiple tables involved.
Because I am using around 10 joined tables with hundreds of thousands rows I will simplify the question and I will provide a mock-up tables:

Table: Territories

| Territory_id | Post_code |
| --- | --- |
| 125315 | 9000 |
| 123458 | 8540 |
| 512133 | 4870 |
| 125322 | 9007 |

Table: Users

| User_id | territory_id | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 125315 | John |
| 2 | 123458 | Bill |
| 3 | 125322 | Cole |
| 4 | 512133 | Kris |

Table: Active_user_territory

| User_id | territory_id | Start_date | End_date | Active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 125315 | 10/03/2020 | 10/03/2023 | 0 |
| 1 | 125315 | 10/03/2023 | 10/03/2050 | 1 |
| 2 | 123458 | 11/03/2023 | 10/03/2050 | 1 |
| 3 | 125322 | 10/03/2020 | 10/03/2023 | 0 |
| 4 | 512133 | 11/03/2020 | 10/03/2023 | 0 |
| 4 | 512133 | 10/03/2018 | 11/03/2020 | 0 |

I need to select user_id, name, post_code, territory_id only in cases when the "Active" status in Active_user_territory table for a given user_id + territory_id combination has only zeroes.

In other words the example with user_id: 1 and territory_id: 125315 should NOT be selected, because for this combination in Active_user_territory table, we have one active record and one inactive. On the other hand for user_id: 4, we have two inactive records, therefore, should be included in the final result.

The output should look like this:

| user_id | name | post_code | territory_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Cole | 9007 | 125322 |
| 4 | Kris | 4870 | 512133 |

Kris and Cole, both have only inactive data in Active_user_territory and they are the output.

I tried to put a filter in the query like so: "WHERE Active = 0", which is obviously incorrect, because it will take also the example for user_id:1 + territory_id:125315 combination.

I believe that I should somehow count the number of 1's per each user_id+territory_id combination and if the count is greater than 0, then exclude it from the final output. It's just that I can not think of a good and efficient way to do this.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By breaking down the query into logical steps you won't have to worry about further grouping columns or dummy aggregates. In this way you can just filter the list of user ids down and proceed with the rest of the joins:

```
with Active_user_territory as (
    select user_id from Active_user_territory
    group by user_id having max(user_id) = 0
)
select *
from Active_user_territory u inner join ...
```

For the scope of the query, references to `Active_user_territory` will go to the CTE definition rather than the base table (except within the definition itself.) You can certainly use a different name for it if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY should help you with this logic:

```
SELECT user_id, territory_id, MAX(active) FROM active_user_territory GROUP BY user_id, territory_id
```

In this case for each user_id + territory_id you will get maximum value from active field.

So, you can use logic like this:

```
SELECT Users.user_id, Users.name, Territories.Post_code, Territories.Territory_id
FROM Active_user_territory
    JOIN Users on Active_user_territory.User_id = Users.User_id
    JOIN Territories on Active_user_territory.territory_id = Territories.Territory_id
GROUP BY Active_user_territory.user_id, Active_user_territory.territory_id
HAVING MAX(active) = 0
```